# Copying files in Python to an existing directory (allow overwriting)

Tags: python, directory, copy

Good evening all,

I am currently trying to learn Python. I thought of a really cool idea today at work to make life easier for myself and my support team and I thought this would be a good starter project to learn Python.
I work for a software company and our current version has a ton of patches that needs to be installed after the initial install. We are currently putting these patches in place manually so I am trying to make my own installer that will just go out and take the patch files and overwrite the current files in place.

I was originally using `shutil.move()` and during the course of fixing code and what not I realized that this was taking the files from my DIR and "moving" them to the new dir (duh).
I didn't want this to happen so I changed it from that to `shutil.copy()` and now I am getting errors and also permissions errors even running PyCharm as an Admin.

I was hoping you could look at my code and give me a helping hand.
Thank you in advance!

```
# Importing the modules

import os
import shutil

src_dir = os.getcwd()

# print("'Copying Files from' + 'tt_source_dir' + 'to' 'tt_target_dir'")
# print(os.listdir())
# not working want it to work

# Moving the TT2018 Folder

tt_source_dir = src_dir + "/TT2018"
tt_target_dir = 'C:\\test'

file_names = os.listdir(tt_source_dir)

for file_names in file_names:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(tt_source_dir, file_names), tt_target_dir)

# Moving the WebPortal Folder

wp_source_dir = src_dir + "/WebPortal"
wp_target_dir = 'C:\\test\Web Portals'

file_names = os.listdir(wp_source_dir)

for file_names in file_names:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(wp_source_dir, file_names), wp_target_dir)

# Moving the SupClient Folder

sc_source_dir = src_dir + "/SupClientTimeZonePatch"
sc_target_dir = 'C:\\test\Client'

file_names = os.listdir(sc_source_dir)

for file_names in file_names:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(sc_source_dir, file_names), sc_target_dir)

# Moving the DBSyncAdmin Folder

dba_source_dir = src_dir + "/DBSyncAdmin"
dba_target_dir = 'C:\\TimeTrakCONNECT\DBSyncServerAdmin'

file_names = os.listdir(dba_source_dir)

for file_names in file_names:
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(dba_source_dir, file_names), dba_target_dir)
```

These are the following errors I am receiving:

```
"C:\Users\Chuck\venv\TimeTrak Patches Installer\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Chuck/PycharmProjects/TimeTrak Patches Installer/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chuck/PycharmProjects/TimeTrak Patches Installer/main.py", line 30, in <module>
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(wp_source_dir, file_names), wp_target_dir)
  File "C:\Users\Chuck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 415, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "C:\Users\Chuck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 261, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc, open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Chuck\\PycharmProjects\\TimeTrak Patches Installer/WebPortal\\bin'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Been playing with this for a couple of days.    
I changed the code to `shutil.copytree` and that seems to have removed my permissions error, but now I have new errors to deal with.    

`line 30, in <module>
    shutil.copytree(os.path.join(wp_source_dir, file_names), wp_target_dir)    
  File "C:\Users\Chuck\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\shutil.py", line 552, in copytree with os.scandir(src) as itr:
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Chuck\\PycharmProjects\\TimeTrak Patches Installer/WebPortal\\About.aspx'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out and I thought I would post the answer to help anyone else having issues with something like this.

The issue I was having was due to my WebPortal folders containing directories + files.
I needed to use os.walk. Another issue I was having was if I ran the program again it wouldn't overwrite the files so I used os.remove to remove the files I was trying to replace while keeping all the other files in that directory intact.

I am not 100% certain this is the end-all fix but as I currently sit this is working for me with no errors.

The WebPortals folder contains Directories and Files and the TT2018 folder only contains files. I could keep that copy simpler.

```
# Importing the modules

import os
import shutil

src_dir = os.getcwd()

# print("'Copying Files from' + 'source_dir' + 'to' 'target_dir'")
# print(os.listdir())
# not working want it to work

# Moving the TT2018 Folder

tt_source_dir = src_dir + "\TT2018"
tt_target_dir = 'C:\\test'

file_names = os.listdir(tt_source_dir)

for file_name in file_names:
    shutil.copy2(os.path.join(tt_source_dir, file_name), tt_target_dir)



# Moving the WebPortal Folder

wp_source_dir = src_dir + "\WebPortal"
wp_target_dir = 'C:\\test\\WebPortal\\'

for source_dir, dirs, file_names in os.walk(wp_source_dir):
    target_dir = source_dir.replace(wp_source_dir, wp_target_dir, 1)

    for file_name in file_names:
        source_file = os.path.join(source_dir, file_name)
        target_file = os.path.join(target_dir, file_name)
        if os.path.exists(target_file):
            # in case of the source and target are the same file
            if os.path.samefile(source_file, target_file):
                continue
            os.remove(target_file)
        shutil.copy2(source_file, target_dir)
```